com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: SignatureDoesNotMatch Error When Uploading Files to S3 from Android App
I'm encountering a SignatureDoesNotMatch error when trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 using the AWS SDK for Java as I'm developing an android app with a feature that allows users to upload their pdf files to s3. Here's the relevant part of the exception stack trace:

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: 51FJW3XAC462RMMR), S3 Extended Request ID: Vu+Emf7n9tm0hk99mBX4Gc3HGHo9o6T5LM+iHGl7S/iiDFH4gb3Iq78h7HOHM/B5i2L204ayVJI=
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:730)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4913)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1960)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.uploadSinglePartAndWaitForCompletion(UploadTask.java:282)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:114)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

I'm using the AWS SDK for Java to upload a file to S3.
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.16.12'
Things I've Checked:
AWS Credentials: I’ve verified that my AWS access key and secret key are correct and have the required permissions.
Bucket Policy: The S3 bucket policy allows all actions from my IP address.
Request Method: I’m using the putObject method from AmazonS3Client.
Region: The region specified in my client configuration matches the S3 bucket’s region.
Here is the code snippet I’m using to upload the file:
AWS S3 Client Initialization:
String accessKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
String secretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
String region = "us-east-1"; // AWS region

// Create AWS credentials
BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

// Create an AmazonS3 client
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, Region.getRegion(region));

transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder().context(getApplicationContext()) 
    .s3Client(s3Client).build();

TransferNetworkLossHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

Upload Function:
private void uploadToS3(File file) {
        // Upload the file to S3
        TransferObserver uploadObserver = transferUtility.upload(
                "XXXXXXXXXXXX", // The S3 bucket to upload to
                file.getName(),         // The key for the uploaded object
                file                // The file where the data to upload exists
        );

        uploadObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                    // Handle successful upload
                    System.out.println("Upload To S3 Successful!");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                float percentDonef = ((float) bytesCurrent / (float) bytesTotal) * 100;
                int percentDone = (int)percentDonef;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                // Handle errors
                Toast.makeText(DocumentView.this, "Upload to S3 failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }


The AWS SDK for Java Version 1 is on the path to deprecation:
Announcing end-of-support for AWS SDK for Java v1.x.
To build Native Android apps look at using the AWS SDK for Kotlin.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html
This SDK works well with Android Studio as discussed here:
Creating a publish/subscription Android application that translates messages using the AWS SDK for Kotlin
S3 operations for this SDK can be found here:
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/kotlin/services/s3
Put Object code example:
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.s3.S3Client
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest
import aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.content.asByteStream
import java.io.File
import kotlin.system.exitProcess
// snippet-end:[s3.kotlin.s3_object_upload.import]

/**
Before running this Kotlin code example, set up your development environment,
including your credentials.

For more information, see the following documentation topic:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html
 */
suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val usage = """
    Usage:
        <bucketName> <objectKey> <objectPath>

    Where:
        bucketName - The Amazon S3 bucket to upload an object into.
        objectKey - The object to upload (for example, book.pdf).
        objectPath - The path where the file is located (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf).
    """

    if (args.size != 3) {
        println(usage)
        exitProcess(0)
    }

    val bucketName = args[0]
    val objectKey = args[1]
    val objectPath = args[2]
    putS3Object(bucketName, objectKey, objectPath)
}

// snippet-start:[s3.kotlin.s3_object_upload.main]
suspend fun putS3Object(
    bucketName: String,
    objectKey: String,
    objectPath: String,
) {
    val metadataVal = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
    metadataVal["myVal"] = "test"

    val request =
        PutObjectRequest {
            bucket = bucketName
            key = objectKey
            metadata = metadataVal
            body = File(objectPath).asByteStream()
        }

    S3Client { region = "us-east-1" }.use { s3 ->
        val response = s3.putObject(request)
        println("Tag information is ${response.eTag}")
    }
}

